# Хотелось бы узнать что такое #pragma и что делает эта директива

Tags: c++

Что такое `#pragma`? Знаю лишь `#pragma once` и то, что эта штука добавляется в заголовочных файлах, для избежания проблем при повторном подключении этого файла.

Comment: Диррективы для компилятора, могут быть разные у каждого комплятора

Answer (score 1):

Директива компилятора. Делает много чего, например, может запускать программу в мультитреде или управлять упаковкой структур в памяти.

У разных компиляторов они свои, смотрите документацию на свой компилятор, чтобы узнать подробности.

[GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html)

[Microsoft Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword?view=msvc-160)

Answer (score 0):

Это директива, которая может много и она сильно компиляторнозависимая. Для студийного компилятора можно почитать на [msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword?view=msvc-160)

мне нравится #pragma comment lib - которая позволяет передать линковщику имя библиотки, которую нужно подключить при линковке. Очень часто бывает супер удобно.

Для gcc - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pragmas.html