# Как сделать приложение одиночку на winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi

Приложение должно запускаться в одном экземпляре. Как это сделать с помощью разделяемой памяти? Если приложение уже загружено, то новый экземпляр должен закрыться, выкинув MessageBox.

Comment: Mutex вам поможет https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5341982/Using-a-Win32-Mutex-to-Figure-Out-if-an-Applicatio

Comment: Странно, но там толкуют о членах IsValid и CloseHandle переменной m_GlobalMutex типа HANDLE. Компилятор таких членов почему-то не знает.

Comment: Именно, создаёте именованный мутекс и в программе проверяете, если мутекс есть при старте, значит программа уже запущена. Имя для мутекса - уникальное делать.

Comment: Это как раз понятно. Вот только члены компилятору не представились.

Comment: С разделяемой памятью - в ответе

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант
LPSTR szName — некоторая определенная заранее константа, например

```
#define MY_PROGRAMM "MyApplication_<тут GUID сгенерированный для уникальности>"

HANDLE hMutex = NULL;

BOOL Alone (LPSTR szName)
{
    hMutex = CreateMutex (NULL, TRUE, szName);
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
    {
        CloseHandle(hMutex);
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

С разделяемой памятью (есть свои особенности):

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.shr,RWS")
#pragma data_seg(".shr")
HWND hGlobal = NULL;
#pragma data_seg()
```

Если переменная hGlobal  установлена, значит запущена копия

А если нет, то устанавливаем её и значит экземпляр запущен

Comment: А зачем нужен MY_PROGRAMM?

Comment: Можете не делать - просто можно так объявить наименование мутекса

Comment: Вот только имя мьютекса у Вас в szName. И используемое ровно один раз за проект лучше же запихать в литерал, не заводя даже именованных констант. Ладно ещё размер массива, его в каждом цикле поминают. А на ровном месте даже нормальные именованные константы избыточны, так макрос ещё и не знает областей видимости.

Comment: А #pragma стандартен?

Comment: @ТарасАтавин https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1216800/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-pragma-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0